# PHPCI Cannot Write to 'config.yml'

Tags: php, jenkins, continuous-integration

I've installed PHPCI. Every thing is perfectly installed. But now when I explores to the setting, an error is displayed as given below:

```
PHPCI cannot write to your config.yml file, settings may not be saved properly until this is rectified.
```

Can someone help me by let me know that how this problem cab get corrected?

Comment: I've never used PHPCI but it looks like it might be a permission issue with your config.yml. Have you tried giving it 755 permission?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

It was because config.yml was created and assigned to `root` user.

Just change the user owning this file to resolve the issue (in my case was www-data because of the vagrant machine)

`chown www-data:www-data config.yml`

Regards

Comment: note to others , apparently the config.yml is inside the PHPCI-directory .