# How to Configure PHPCI for a Laravel Project to Deploy the Code Automatically on the Server?

Tags: php, deployment, jenkins, continuous-integration, web-deployment

I'm working on a project with my team. We decided to use PHPCI as Continuous Integration tool for our project.

We've Installed PHPCI on the server, created a virtual host for it and it's  working fine.

Now I don't know:

1. How to setup the 'yml' file for the project?
2. How to automatically deploy the committed code on our live server?

I've also asked a question about it before on approximately similar topic. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33657957/phpci-cannot-write-to-config-yml) it is and seek help in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33657957/phpci-cannot-write-to-config-yml) question.